# Laravel - Dynamic Wildcard Subdomain Creation on GoDaddy Server

Tags: laravel, routes, wildcard-subdomain

I want to create wildcard dynamic subdomain on GoDaddy server with Laravel framework.

For this.

I have added A record in my DNS zone in domain setting like this...

[image]

Then in Laravel routes file I have added like this....

[image]

But then also it is not working proper as I wanted.

So anybody can please check and help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.